# How does spark behave without enough memory (RAM) to create RDD

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

When I do `sc.textFile("abc.txt")`
Spark creates RDD in RAM (memory).

1. So does the cluster collective memory should be greater than size of the file “abc.txt”?
2. My worker nodes have disk space so could I use disk space while reading texfile to create RDD? If so how to do it?
3. How to work on big data which doesn’t fit into memory?

Answer (score 1):

> When I do sc.textFile("abc.txt") Spark creates RDD in RAM (memory).

The above point is not certainly true. In Spark, their is something called [transformations](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-transformations.html)  and something called [actions](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-actions.html). `sc.textFile("abc.txt")` is transformation operation and it does not simply load data straight away unless you trigger any action  eg `count()`.

To give you a collective answer to your all questions, I would urge you to understand how [spark execution works](http://balajireddyblog.blogspot.in/2017/01/spark-execution.html). Their is something called logical and physical plans.As part of physical plan, it does *cost calculation*(available resource calculation across the cluster(s)) before it starts the jobs. if you understand them, you will get clear idea on all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You first assumption is incorrect:

> Spark creates RDD in RAM (memory).

Spark doesn't create RDDs "in-memory". It uses memory but it is not limited to in-memory data processing. So:

- > So does the cluster collective memory should be greater than size of the file “abc.txt”?

  No
- > My worker nodes have disk space so could I use disk space while reading texfile to create RDD? If so how to do it?

  No special steps are required.
- > How to work on big data which doesn’t fit into memory?

  See above.